# CURL request not working anymore with cert

Tags: curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, p12

I have a command in CURL that was working find since the beggining of the year.
This week it started to failed.

This is the command

```
curl -X POST --url https://destination/login -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username": "my-username","password":"mypassword"}' --cert cert.p12  --key 'textkey'
```

While this was working fine last week, now I get the following error:

```
curl: (58) unable to load client cert: -8018 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PKCS11_ERROR)
```

This is being executed in a Centos 7.

We do not upgrade anything, not sure if the OS for itself do something else.. But I guess not.

As per some googling, I found that the issue could be in the cert or the password, but it was working as expected last week without any change.

Comment: Could you try with: `curl -X POST --url https://destination/login -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username": "my-username","password":"mypassword"}' --cert cert.p12:textkey -cert-type P12` ?